# Use VBScript to VLOOKUP values, or evaluate formula?

Tags: vbscript, libreoffice-calc

For processing orders we're using VBScripts to import them into accounting software. There are several suppliers, each with their own file format, mostly CSV and XML. The first step is to extract all the order lines (custom function per supplier), do some additional processing and then write it to the database, which is the same for all suppliers.

One new supplier uses Excel files with all the order lines in one sheet, except for the corresponding VAT percentage value which are available in another sheet. The VAT percentage per item can be looked up using the `itemcode` from the order sheet.

[image: Libreoffice Calc VLOOKUP a VAT value on another sheet]

The company only has LibreOffice Calc and I understand you could do something like this in macro. However, it is a fully automated process and every other file is already handled by VBScript so I'd rather not make an exception or handle just this one order type manually (opening Calc and running the macro). So it has to be **VBS and LibreOffice** in this case.

Here is the VBScript code I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

' variables
Dim oSM, oDesk
Dim sFilename
Dim oDoc
Dim oSheet

Dim iLine

Dim sCode, iCount, sDesc, fCost, Perc

Set oSM = WScript.CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") 
Set oDesk = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop") 

sFilename = "file:///C:/orders/import/supplier_orderlist_08-01-2019.xls"

set oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL( sFilename, "_blank", 0, Array() ) 
set oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByName("Orderlist")

For iLine = 11 to 12 ' testing first 2 lines

    sCode   = oSheet.getCellByPosition(1, iLine).getString()
    iCount  = oSheet.getCellByPosition(2, iLine).getString()
    sDesc   = oSheet.getCellByPosition(5, iLine).getString()
    fCost   = oSheet.getCellByPosition(8, iLine).getString()

    'lookup doesn't work
    Perc    = Macro_VLOOKUP(sCode, oDoc)

    WScript.Echo sCode & " - " & iCount  & "x - " & sDesc & " => " & fCost & ", " & Perc & "%"
Next 'iLine

WScript.Quit 1

Function Macro_VLOOKUP(SearchValue, oDocGlob)
    Dim oSheetLook, CellRange
    Dim Column, Mode, svc, arg, Value

    Set oSheetLook = oDocGlob.getSheets().getByName("Itemlisttotal")
    Set CellRange = oSheetLook.getCellRangeByName("A1:B10000")

    Column = 1
    Mode = 0
    svc = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess") '<- error: variable not defined
    arg = Array(SearchValue, CellRange, Column, Mode)
    Value = svc.callFunction("VLOOKUP", arg)
    Macro_VLOOKUP = Value
End Function
```

It gives an error on the line with `createUnoService`:

> Variable not defined 'createUnoService'

which is probably a LibreOffice Basic function and needs to be translated to the VBScript equivalent. There isn't much documentation or examples on this, so I can only guess, but `Set svc = WScript.CreateObject("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")` also doesn't work and gives a "class name not found" error.

Is it possible to do a VLOOKUP (or something similar) from VBScript in LibreOffice Calc?

Or is there a way to evaluate a cell formula from a string at runtime?

Comment: you have NOT defined the object svc, 
add a line at the top of your program as 

DIM svc

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't paste my completed code after all testing. I had all the variables defined, but still `createUnoService` was not found. I searched online some more, and I will try this code http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wp-ood.vbs.html

Comment: The code document in that link is for converting WORD PERFECT documents to either Microsoft Word or to PDF format of the same document. I think what you ought to be looking  would be on the Libre Office Documentation on their own website ... A good starting point would be https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star.html or even https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sheet_1_1SheetRangesQuery.html#ae9f7fedf78bd70525c0ba4a92fdd41f7

Comment: I'd already found and looked at this documentation (https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sheet_1_1FunctionAccess.html) but I cannot make heads or tails of it. From what I can gather it is a programmers reference, so for the inner workings of LibreOffice in C++, not intended for end users.